# Javascript not getting called from html button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have the following html page with the button "NewPatients" that I am trying to set up to open up a modal with a form to fill out. I can't seem to get the modal to come up. The "openModal" function in the javascript doesn't seem to be getting called.

cshtml file:

```
@using PracticeApp.Controllers

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Patients";
}

<script src="@Url.Content("../../Js/PatientFormModal.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="title">
    <div>
        <h1 style="float: left">@ViewBag.Title</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="rmm" style="float: right; display: inline-block">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="NewPatient">New Patient</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="DeleteLink">Delete Patient(s)</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <div id="modal_window">
        <div style="text-align: right;"><a id="modal_close" href="#">close <b>X</b></a></div>

        <p>Complete the form below to add a new patient:</p>

        <form id="add_patient" method="POST" action="#" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        <p><label>First Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" name="fname" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Last Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" name="lname" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Birthdate (mm/dd/yyyy)<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" name="bday" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>Practice Name<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" name="location" value=""></label></p>
        <p><label>SSN<strong>*</strong><br>
        <input type="text" autofocus required size="48" name="ssn" value=""></label></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="feedbackForm" value="Add Patient"></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the javascript file. PatientFormModal.js:

```
var checkForm = function (e) {

    var dateRegEx = /^((0?[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)?[0-9]{2})*$/;
    var form = (e.target) ? e.target : e.srcElement;

    var modal_init = function () {
        var wrapper = document.getElementById("content");
        var window = document.getElementById("modal_window");

        var openModal = function (e) {
            alert("Here");
            wrapper.className = "overlay";
            window.style.marginTop = (-modal_window.offsetHeight) / 2 + "px";
            window.style.marginLeft = (-modal_window.offsetWidth) / 2 + "px";
            e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        };

        var closeModal = function (e) {
            wrapper.className = "";
            e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        };

        var clickHandler = function (e) {
            if (!e.target) e.target = e.srcElement;
            if (e.target.tagName == "DIV") {
                if (e.target.id != "modal_window") closeModal(e);
            }
        };

        var keyHandler = function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 27) closeModal(e);
        };

        if (document.addEventListener) {
            document.getElementById("NewPatient").addEventListener("click", openModal, false);
            document.getElementById("modal_close").addEventListener("click", closeModal, false);
            document.addEventListener("click", clickHandler, false);
            document.addEventListener("keydown", keyHandler, false);
        } else {
            document.getElementById("NewPatient").attachEvent("onclick", openModal);
            document.getElementById("modal_close").attachEvent("onclick", closeModal);
            document.attachEvent("onclick", clickHandler);
            document.attachEvent("onkeydown", keyHandler);
        }
    };

    if (form.fname.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter patient's first name");
        form.fname.focus();
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        return;
    }
    if (form.lname.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter patient's last name");
        form.lname.focus();
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        return;
    }
    if (form.bday.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter patient's date of birth");
        form.bday.focus();
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        return;
    }
    if (document.add_patient.bday.value.search(dateRegEx)==-1) {
        alert("Please enter patient's date of birth in the specified format");
    }
    if (form.location.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter patient's practice name");
        form.location.focus();
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        return;
    }
    if (form.ssn.value == "") {
        alert("Please enter patient's SSN");
        form.ssn.focus();
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        return;
    }

    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.getElementById("add_patient").addEventListener("submit", checkForm, false);
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", modal_init, false);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("add_patient").attachEvent("onsubmit", checkForm);
        window.attachEvent("onload", modal_init);
    }
};
```

Here is CSS for the modal as well:

```
.content.overlay:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  }

  #modal_window {
    display: none;
    z-index: 200;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    width: 360px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #999;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  }

  .content.overlay #modal_window {
    display: block;
  }
```

Comment: do you ever call the "checkForm" function? if no then no wonder that nothing happens....

Comment: I guess not. how should I call checkForm? **edit** there is a call to checkForm is at the bottom of the javascript file. is that what you are referring to?

Comment: I'd put the <script.....> right before the </body> and then just add the checkForm() at the end of your script file...

Comment: There isn't a </body> tag on this page. I am using a shared layout that has the <body> tags on it. This is just a page that gets called by the shared layout to get displayed in the <body> element of the shared layout.

Comment: ok it should work if you just put it at the end of your html file then BUT I would recommend you to try jquery or something similar because it might make stuff easier since there were many people who thought about making things like validation simpler and so on

Comment: There also exist validations built in in almost every browser via HTML5 which you also could have a look at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script loads before the HTML does, therefore the DOM element `NewPatient` is not yet available -> event doesn't get attached -> click doesn't work.

Call the `PatientFormModal.js` after the HTML.

**EDIT:** It also looks your JS doesn't get called, so add `checkForm()` at the end of you JS file.

Comment: In this particular case it doesn't matter since the script file only declares a function which itself isn't executed BEFORE the html finished loading.

Comment: BUT i aggree that putting the script is always better at the bottom of the html

Comment: I moved it down below the final <div> but its still not working. grrr. I was really hoping that would be the simple fix. lol

Comment: @AtlasBowler Don't worry, we'll figure it out! Can you put a `console.log('test')` inside the `modal_init` function to see if it gets called?

Comment: added it and nothing came up in the console so it doesn't look like it is getting called.

Comment: @AtlasBowler I think i know why. Doesn't look like anything is triggering `checkForm`. I suggest you add a `checkForm()` as well.

Comment: do i just add "`checkForm()`" at the bottom of the js file and that's it?

Comment: @AtlasBowler Hopefully, yeah :)

Comment: looks like that gave me access to it because now I am getting errors in the console. lol its a start, now to work on fixing my errors. :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68968/discussion-between-atlasbowler-and-omri-aharon).